# Laravel: Ordering data at a query level when using pivot tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my `routes/web.php` I have a route like this...

```
Route::get('/tags/{tag}', 'TagsController@show');
```

Then, inside `TagsController` because I have a `post_tag` pivot table that has been defined as a many-to-many relationship.

Tag.php...

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}

public function getRouteKeyName(){
  return 'name';
}
```

Post.php...

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

I get the posts for a certain tag like this...

```
public function show(Tag $tag){
    $posts = $tag->posts;
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts','tag'));
}
```

Then, to sort the posts into newest first I can do this in `index.blade.php`...

```
      @foreach ($posts->sortByDesc('created_at') as $post)
         @include('posts.post')
      @endforeach
```

This works fine, but I'm doing the re-ordering at collection level when I'd prefer to do it at query level.

From [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) I can see that I can do something like this, which also works...

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    //
}
```

But, something like this does not seem to work...

```
public function show($tag){
    $posts = \App\Tag::find($tag);
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

My question is, how can I filter/order the data at a query level when using pivot tables?

Comment: can you show your relation function posts?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the relationships. The `getRouteKeyName` is there also so I've kept that in there, although I have tried taking it out to try different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To order your collection you must change

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

to

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->orderBy('created_at');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm obviously very new to Laravel so I'll play around with that. That's modifying the actual relationship, which isn't what I was expecting.

Comment: Thanks again. I ended up using something similar but just in the `show` method. I think it's technically not query level because it uses `sortBy` as opposed to `orderBy` but this has the kind of simplicity I was looking for and can also allow for `where` clauses, etc... `$posts = $tag->posts->where('id','>',4)->sortByDesc('created_at');`

Comment: I guess the `belongsToMany` is the query.

Comment: belongsToMany is the query and where and sortByDesc. this are all eloquent methods that converts to a sql query

Answer (score 1):

## Extending @leli. 1337 answer

To order content without changing the relation created.

First, keep the original relation

```
class User 
{ 
    public function tags
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
}
```

Second, during query building do the following

```
//say you are doing query building

$users = User::with([
    'tags' => function($query) {
         $query->orderBy('tags.created_at','desc');
    }
])->get();
```

With this, you can order the content of tags data and in query level also if needed you can add more where clauses to the tags table query builder.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this code, modified to my purpose and it did work with the `orderBy` as you have posted but I was unable to use any `where` statements with it, but I undoubtedly made a mistake somewhere. I ended up with going for a modified version of what @leli-1337 said.